# Connecting to PostgreSQL using QGIS using a VirtualMachine?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I installed Postgresql in Windows server 2012 Essential on Virtual Machine.

Everything works ok , but when  i try to use QGIS Desktop which is on desktop installed to access to Postgresql-data , the connection fails or (Error), known that i use the IP of virtual machine in Host. see image

[image]

Comment: Have you configured the Postgres instances of the pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf to allow connections from you QGIS machine IP?

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying, yes i have already configured the Pg_hba to allow connections? but what do you mean with configuring Postresql.conf? because o thought that configuring pg_hba is enough

Comment: Can you ping the VM from your host machine? what VM software are you using? I use Virtualbox and need to set the network type to 'bridged', then open up the PGSQL ports to accept connections from all clients... although you're using windows, here's the settings in the files you should change: https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS22UbuntuPGSQL95Apt#OpenAccesstoClients

Comment: im using  Vmworkstation Pro

Comment: Here's some info on bridged mode - you need to make sure your host can talk to your VM before your postgresql connection will work: http://pubs.vmware.com/ws7_ace26/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm?context=ws_user&file=ws_net_configurations_bridged.html

Comment: @IR-GM 
Look for listen_addresses = 'localhost' in your postgresql.conf file and change it to listen_addresses = '*'

Comment: @maw269 already did

Comment: i can ping the VM from desktop but not reverse that mean i cant ping local machine from Virtual machine, i don't know if is normal,! and actually the goal behind all of this to simulate if The  Qgis users can access to the data in PostgreSQL which is installed on server or not?